# Catch a UIImageView from a different .XIB

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, xcode4

Dudes from this holy sanctuary,

New problem! I need to get the UIImageView from a different .XIB.
Let me put it in code so it get's simpler:

1)

```
-(UIImage *)grabScreenImage{

    //screen = IBOutlet for the UIImageView

    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(self.screen.frame.size);
    [(CALayer *)self.view.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
    UIImage *image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
    NSLog(@"PASSED BY THE PHOTO DUDES");
    return image;

}
```

2)

```
-(UIImage *)takeGraphScreenImage{

//shouldBeGraphViewController = IBOutlet for the other UIViewController
//shouldBeGraph = IBOutLet for the UIImageView in the ShouldBeGraphViewController

        UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(shouldBeGraphViewController.shouldBeTheGraph.frame.size);
        [(CALayer *)shouldBeGraphViewController.shouldBeTheGraph.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
        UIImage *image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
        UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
        return image;
    }
```

## (1) works just fine, i capture the image and send it to by email but (2) doesn't.

i just copied and pasted and changed some parameters so it could be used by the other but it gives me loads of errors.

3) -(IBAction)sendMail{

```
MFMailComposeViewController *mailComposer = [[MFMailComposeViewController alloc]init];

UIImage *curretScreen = [[self takeGrabScreenImage]retain];
UIImage *graphScreen = [[self takeGraphScreenImage]retain];

if ([MFMailComposeViewController canSendMail]){
    NSLog(@"ENTERED THE GOOD PART OF THE IF");
    mailComposer.mailComposeDelegate = self;
    [mailComposer setSubject:@"MY SCREENSHOT TEST"];
    [mailComposer addAttachmentData:UIImagePNGRepresentation(curretScreen) mimeType:@"image/png" fileName:@"SCREENSHOT"];
    [mailComposer addAttachmentData:UIImagePNGRepresentation(graphScreen) mimeType:@"image/png" fileName:@"SCREENSHOT-02"];

    //NSArray* paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    //NSString* documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];

    /*for (NSString *x in [self.photoLocations allKeys]){
        NSString *fullPath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:x];
        UIImage *item = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:fullPath];
        [mailComposer addAttachmentData:UIImagePNGRepresentation(item, 0.5) mimeType:@"image/jpeg" fileName:
    }*/

} else { ... }

[mailComposer setMessageBody:@"PUT YOUR MESSAGE HERE" isHTML:NO];
[self presentModalViewController:mailComposer animated:YES];
[mailComposer release];
[curretScreen release];
```

}

I just need to take screenshots from both UIImageViews (from the two UIViewControllers) and send them by email, the email part is done and taking the first screenshot too, but take the second screenshot doesn't.  Gives me erros like these:

```
Mon May 16 21:02:46 FGringo EmailSending[1036] <Error>: CGContextSaveGState: invalid context 0x0
Mon May 16 21:02:46 FGringo EmailSending[1036] <Error>: CGContextSetAlpha: invalid context 0x0
```

Help me, Please! (:

Answer (score 0):

```
- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker
didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info
{
    // Dismiss image picker modal.
    [picker dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];

    if ([MFMailComposeViewController canSendMail]) {
        // Create a string with HTML formatting for the email body.
        NSMutableString *emailBody = [[NSMutableString alloc] initWithString:@"<html><body>"];

        // Add some text to it.
        [emailBody appendString:@"<p>Body text goes here.</p>"];

        // You could repeat here with more text or images, otherwise
        // close the HTML formatting.
        [emailBody appendString:@"</body></html>"];
        NSLog(@"%@", emailBody);

        // Create the mail composer window.
        MFMailComposeViewController *emailDialog = [[MFMailComposeViewController alloc] init];
        emailDialog.mailComposeDelegate = self;

        // Image to insert.
        UIImage *emailImage = [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];

        if (emailImage != nil) {
            NSData *data = UIImagePNGRepresentation(emailImage);
            [emailDialog addAttachmentData:data mimeType:@"image/png" fileName:@"filename_goes_here.png"];
        }

        [emailDialog setSubject:@"Subject goes here."];
        [emailDialog setMessageBody:emailBody isHTML:YES];

        [self presentModalViewController:emailDialog animated:YES];
        [emailDialog release];
        [emailBody release];
    }
}
```

Comment: it's no quite that. Because i already have code for sending and attaching, but as i explained the problem is: That i am in one view "Principal View" and i need to take "screenshots" from this "Principal View" and a "Secundary View" but the "send mail" button is on the "Principal View".